# working with list columns in r (data.table/dplyr)

Tags: r, data-structures, dplyr, data.table, purrr

I have a large dataset organized in listcolumns (20Gb).

1-Is there any other tricks I can use to speed up the following code? Data.table seems to provide a two-fold increase, but I assume there are other tricks that can be used in similar scenarios.

2-Apart from saveRDS - is there any other faster file-libraries (vroom, fst and fwrite do not seem to support listcols) supporting listcolumns?

3-I tried `dt[,.(test=tib_sort[tib_sort[, .I[.N]], stringi::stri_sub(dt$ch, length = 5)],by=id)]`but it throws an incorrect number of dimensions error. Is there an option to do `by` using a listcolumn and automatically have it setDT and key/index?

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(data.table)
library(tictoc)
```

#### Toy data

```
set.seed(123)
tib <-
  tibble(id = 1:20000) %>% mutate(k = map_int(id,  ~ sample(c(10:30), 1)))
tib <-
  tib %>% mutate(tib_df = map(k,  ~ tibble(
    ch = replicate(.x, paste0(
      sample(letters[1:24],
             size = sample(c(10:20), 1)),
      collapse = ""
    )),
    num = sample(1:1e10, .x,replace = F)
  )))
```

### Dplyr

```
help <- function(df) {
  df <- df %>% top_n(1, num) %>% select(ch)
  stringi::stri_sub(df, length = 5)
}
tic("purrr")
tib <- tib %>% mutate(result = map_chr(tib_df, help))
toc(log = T, quiet = T)
```

### Data.table

```
dt <- copy(tib)
setDT(dt)
tic("setDT w key")
dt[, tib_df := lapply(tib_df, setDT)]
dt[, tib_sort := lapply(tib_df, function(x)
  setindex(x, "num"))]
toc(log = T, quiet = T)
tic("dt w key")
dt[, result_dt_key := sapply(tib_df, function(x) {
  x[x[, .I[.N]], stringi::stri_sub(ch, length = 5)]
})]
toc(log=T, quiet = T)
```

## Timing

```
    tic.log(format = T)
[[1]]
[1] "purrr: 25.499 sec elapsed"

[[2]]
[1] "setDT w key: 4.875 sec elapsed"

[[3]]
[1] "dt w key: 12.077 sec elapsed"
```

## EDITS and update after also including unnested versions from both dplyr and data.table

```
1 purrr: 25.824 sec elapsed          
2 setDT wo key: 2.97 sec elapsed     
3 dt wo key: 13.724 sec elapsed      
4 setDT w key: 1.778 sec elapsed     
5 dt w key: 11.489 sec elapsed       
6 dplyr,unnest: 1.496 sec elapsed    
7 dt,I,unnest: 0.329 sec elapsed     
8 dt, join, unnest: 0.325 sec elapsed

tic("dt, join, unnest")
b <- unnest(tib)
setDT(b)
unnest.J <- b[b[, .(num=max(num)), by = 'id'], on=c('id','num')][,r2:=stringi::stri_sub(ch,length=5)][]
toc(log=T)

 res <- list(unnest.J$r2,tib2$result2,dt$result_dt_key,dt$result_dt,tib$result)
 sapply(res,identical,unnest.I$r2)
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

So- I guess the lesson learnt is that although listcolumns look deceivingly tempting as data structures for analysis, they are much **slooower**.

[image]

Comment: Is it necessary to keep the data structure? I think most of the time it makes more sense to `unnest`.

Comment: It is not absolutely necessary, but I find that the structure increases legibility for the analysis.

Comment: You might also want to check that you're getting the same results with each way. I think setindex doesn't sort the data as you're expecting (for which you'd want setkey); and if there are ties at the max num, you'll get multiple rows per df with the join way while the others only return one row. (I see you generate num by sampling without replacement, but maybe it's an issue with the real application.)

Comment: @Frank thanks for the suggestion re equal results. See the edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operating on list columns tends to be slow, as the functions have to iterate over the entries and can't be vectorized. Usually it thus makes sense to `unnest` list columns:

```
tic("unnest")
tib2 <- tib %>% 
  tidyr::unnest(tib_df) %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  top_n(1, num) %>% 
  mutate(result = stringi::stri_sub(ch, length = 5))
toc(log = T, quiet = T)
```

Result:

```
> tic.log(format = T)
[[1]]
[1] "purrr: 39.54 sec elapsed"

[[2]]
[1] "setDT w key: 10.7 sec elapsed"

[[3]]
[1] "dt w key: 19.19 sec elapsed"

[[4]]
[1] "unnest: 1.62 sec elapsed"
```

With your toy data, the final object is only slightly different. But if it is necessary to get the original form back, you might want to do something like this:

```
tic("unnest+reattach")
tib2 <- tib %>% 
  tidyr::unnest(tib_df) %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  top_n(1, num) %>% 
  mutate(result = stringi::stri_sub(ch, length = 5))

tib3 <- tib %>% 
  mutate(result = tib2$result[match(id, tib2$id)])

toc(log = T, quiet = T)

tic.log(format = T)[[5]]
[1] "unnest+reattach: 1.83 sec elapsed"
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I´ll revert to normal data structures ASAP. See my edit.